# How do you make a start/stop button for a function?

Tags: javascript

Anyone know how I could make a start/stop button that would control this slideshow in javascript?

```
<script>
    var slideIndex = 0;
    showSlides();

    function showSlides() {
        var i;
        var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            slides[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        slideIndex++;
        if (slideIndex > slides.length) { slideIndex = 1 }
        for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
        dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
        setTimeout(showSlides, 4000); // Change image every 4 seconds
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Surround the `setTimeout` in an if statement?

Comment: Would you mind clarifying a bit more? I an just a beginner.

Comment: Hi. Please add your whole code, we need to see the bug to be able to help you.

Comment: I think you can deal with `setTimeout` function by setting it to a variable and then when your button is clicked use `clearTimeout` if you post your html, css that will be more helpful to get a better answer

Comment: will do Alexandre. Just a few minutes.

Comment: I can't seem to post the html. It says it is not formatted correctly. Uggg. I am terrible at this stuff.

Comment: This is my first try using jsfiddle. Can you tell me if y'all can see this? This is what I have tried so far. I am not sure what to do with the button.

https://jsfiddle.net/tamtamToronto/eqk4rLus/2/#&togetherjs=jVy2hdrMtl

Comment: That is not how to use `setTimeout`, and to create a recurring action like a slideshow you should be using `setInterval`. You have got to [read the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Timeouts_and_intervals), this stuff is simply too complicated to try to guess your way through it.

Comment: @TamTaminToronto your fiddle and your post is really the worest and if you wasn't beginner i wasn't losing the time for editing your code but anyway check this pen you will find your code after editing https://codepen.io/zxcvpn/pen/YzQPdLz

Answer (score 1):

```js
let timerInterval;

const incrementTimer = () => {
  const counterPara = document.querySelector('#counter');
  let counterVal = parseInt(counterPara.textContent);
  counterPara.textContent = counterVal + 1;
}

const startTimer = () => {
  timerInterval = setInterval(incrementTimer, 1000);
}

const stopTimer = () => {
  clearInterval(timerInterval);
}
```

```html
<p id="counter">0</p>
<button onclick="startTimer()">Start</button>
<button onclick="stopTimer()">Stop</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use setInterval and clearInterval. Like that:

```
function start() {var timer = setInverval(showSlides,4000)}
function stop() {clearInterval(timer)}
```

Comment: Thanks I will try to figure that out. I am just a beginner. So like <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
And you put setInterval instead of myFunction?

Comment: Does this go outside the function or inside?

Comment: Use one function that use setInverval to start the slide show. Set interval return the id of the interval. the Id you can use to clear the interval, that would be your Stop function then.

Comment: Like that: 
function start() {var timer = setInverval(showSlides,4000)}
function stop() {clearInterval(timer)}

Comment: Trying these things out. Sorry I am very slow.

Comment: Moritz, how do I control the function you specified with the button. Is it something like this with the function name inside?
 <button onclick="start()">Click me</button>

Comment: I have tried posting this on jsfiddle. See if you can view this and see if I am close to a solution? I am not quite sure what to do with the button.
https://jsfiddle.net/tamtamToronto/eqk4rLus/2/#&togetherjs=jVy2hdrMtl